# move the camera to face the selected object 3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, tween.js

so this is the first time i try to learn how to create web with 3 js and tween js. i created multiple object when user click 1 of object it will display its content. but when i try to move the camera to face the object (zooming and focus on the selected the object), the camera just jump to the top of canvas and scan all of the canvas.

```
(function() {
    var DZOOM, OX, OY, aspectt, camera, height, light, loader, render, renderer, scene, view, width, raycaster, intersects, INTERSECTED;
    var objects = [],
    uuids   = [], 
    names   = [];

    var container = document.getElementById( 'main-content' );
    var windowHalfX = container.offsetWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = container.offsetHeight / 2;
    width  = container.offsetWidth;
    height = container.offsetHeight;


    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
    INTERSECTED;
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    aspectt = width / height;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( '#fff' );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(85, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true,
        antialias: true
    });

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    function onWindowResize() {
        windowHalfX = container.offsetWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = container.offsetHeight / 2;
        camera.aspect = container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight );
    }


    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);

    light.position.set(15, -5, 15);

    scene.add(light);



    OX = -35;

    OY = -5;

    if (!deviceIsMobile()) {
        camera.position.set(OX + 60, OY - 5, 35);
    }
    else{
        camera.position.set(OX + 30, OY - 10, 20);
    }
    camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(OX, OY, 0));

    container.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    container.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    container.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

    function displayCaptionOnClick( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
        intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects[0].children, true );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
               displayCaption(intersects[0].object.uuid);
            }               

        }

    }


    function redOnHover( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
        intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects[0].children, true );
        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                    INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
                    INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( 0xff0000 ); 
                }

        } else {

            if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

            INTERSECTED = null;

        }

    }

    function toObj(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3().getNormalMatrix( obj.matrixWorld );
        var worldNormal = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1).applyMatrix3( normalMatrix ).normalize();
            console.log(worldNormal);
        var camPosition = new THREE.Vector3().copy(obj.position).add(worldNormal.multiplyScalar(100));

        var rotateTween = new TWEEN.Tween(lookAtVector)
            .to({
                x: obj.position.x,
                y: obj.position.y,
                z: obj.position.z
            }, 4000)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
            .onUpdate(function(){
                camera.lookAt(lookAtVector);
            })
            .onComplete(function(){
                lookAtVector.copy(obj.position);
            })
            .start();

            var goTween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position)
            .to(camPosition, 4000)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
            .start();
    }

    function displayCaption( uuid ) {

        var curObj = uuids.indexOf(uuid);
        console.log(curObj);
        if(curObj<=7){
            $('.single-page').hide();
            var crnt= $('#'+curObj);
            crnt.show();
            $('#sidebar').animate({right:0});
            redOnHover( event );
        }

    }


    var targetRotation = 0;
    var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;


    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        render();
    }

    render = function() {
        TWEEN.update();

        camera.updateMatrixWorld();

        return renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        container.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        container.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        container.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
        mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

        checkClick(event);

        displayCaptionOnClick( event );
        toObj(INTERSECTED);
    }    

    var myObj;
    loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load("js/try.dae.json",function ( obj ) {


        if (!deviceIsMobile()) {
            obj.scale.x = obj.scale.y = obj.scale.z = 2.3;
        }
        else{
            obj.scale.x = obj.scale.y = obj.scale.z = 0.8;
        }
        // FIXED
        obj.position.x = -15;
        obj.position.y = -5;
        obj.position.z = 24;
        obj.rotation.y = 0.15;
        obj.rotation.z = 0.6;
        myObj = obj;
        scene.add( obj );
        objects.push(obj);
        console.log(objects);

        var exclude = ["Cylinder_007", "Cube_005", "Cube_004", "Cylinder_006", "Cylinder_005", "Cylinder_004", "Cylinder_003", "Cylinder_002", "Plane_004", "Plane_003", "Plane_002", "Cube_003", "Cube_002", "Cube", "Cube_001", "Cylinder_001", "Plane_001", "Cylinder", "Torus_001", "Text"];
        for( var i = 0; i < objects[0].children.length; i++ ) {
           if ( exclude.indexOf(objects[0].children[i].name) < 0  ) {
                uuids.push(objects[0].children[i].children[0].uuid);
           }
        }
        for( var i = 0; i < objects[0].children.length; i++ ) {
            uuids.push(objects[0].children[i].children[0].uuid);
        }

        return render();
    });
    animate();
}).call(this);
```